# How to split data in a dataframe cell and perform a Pandas groupby on splits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have produced some data which lists parks in proximity to different areas of East London with use of the FourSquare API. It here in the dataframe, df.

```
Location,Parks,Borough
Aldborough Hatch,Fairlop Waters Country Park,Redbridge
Ardleigh Green,Haynes Park,Havering
Bethnal Green,"Haggerston Park, Weavers Fields",Tower Hamlets
Bromley-by-Bow,"Rounton Park, Grove Hall Park",Tower Hamlets
Cambridge Heath,"Haggerston Park, London Fields",Tower Hamlets
Dalston,"Haggerston Park, London Fields",Hackney
```

Import data with `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')`

What I would like to do is group by the borough column and count the distinct parks in that borough so that for example 'Tower Hamlets' = 5 and 'Hackney' = 2. I will create a new dataframe for this purpose which simply lists total number of parks for each borough present in the dataframe.

I know I can do:

```
df.groupby(['Borough', 'Parks']).size()
```

But I need to split parks by the delimiter ',' such that they are treated as unique, distinct entities for a borough.

What do you suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean : `df.groupby('Borough')['Parks'].agg(','.join)` ?

Comment: df.parl.str.split(',',expand=True)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The first rule of data science is to clean your data into a useful format.**

## Reformat the `DataFrame` to be usable:

```
df.Parks = df.Parks.str.split(',\s*') # per user piRSquared
df = df.explode('Parks') # pandas v 0.25
```

[image: cleaned DataFrame]

## Now the DataFrame is in a proper format that can be more easily analyzed

```
df.groupby('Borough').Parks.nunique()

Borough
Hackney          2
Havering         1
Redbridge        1
Tower Hamlets    5
```

- That's three lines of code, but now the `DataFrame` is in a useful format, upon which more insights can easily be extracted.

## Plot

```
df.groupby(['Borough']).Parks.nunique().plot(kind='bar', title='Unique Parks Counts by Borough')
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer - thanks! Had previously been using Pandas 0.24. Loving this explode function.

Comment: My humble apologies for the late response

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Pandas 0.25 or greater, consider the answer from [Trenton_M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57363546/2336654)
His answer provides a good suggestion for creating a more useful data set.

IIUC:

```
df.groupby('Borough').Parks.apply(
    lambda s: len(set(', '.join(s).split(', ')))
)

Borough
Hackney          2
Havering         1
Redbridge        1
Tower Hamlets    5
Name: Parks, dtype: int64
```

Similar

```
df.Parks.str.split(', ').groupby(df.Borough).apply(lambda s: len(set().union(*s)))

Borough
Hackney          2
Havering         1
Redbridge        1
Tower Hamlets    5
Name: Parks, dtype: int64
```